# How to apply the axioms in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Consider these axioms, from my book:

> **Axiom of equality**   $∀x ∀y [x = y → ∀z (x ∈ z ↔ y ∈ z)]$
>
> **Axiom of extensionality** $∀x ∀y [x = y ↔ ∀u (u ∈ x ↔ u ∈ y)]$
>
> **The Axiom of Existence** $∃z z = ∅$
>
> **The Axiom of Pairing** $∀x ∀y ∃z z = \{x, y\}$

I understand these axioms,  and I am given a theorem and the exercise of solving the $4,5$ parts(not homework, really, I'm self studying this), but I don't get how to apply them. The book says that the first 3 are immediate consequences of the Axiom of Extensionality, but is that all? I don't see how they are immdeiate consequences.

I am used to applying simple properties like,

$\forall a \forall b \forall c(a=b \implies a+c = b+c)$, but These axioms are hard to work with.

> **Theorem 1:**
>
> $\qquad{1)} (\forall x) x=x$
>
> $\qquad{2)} ∀x ∀y x = y → y = x$
>
> $\qquad{3)} ∀x ∀y ∀z [(x = y ∧ y = z) → x = z$
>
> $\qquad{4)} ∀x ∀y ∃z z = <x, y>$
>
> $\qquad{5)} ∀u ∀v ∀x ∀y [<u, v> = <x, y> ↔ (u = x ∧ v = y)].$

How do you correctly apply the axioms?

Edit: Book Title

An Introduction To Set Theory

by Professor William A. R. Weiss

http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf

Comment: 2) is straightforward using the answer below: from $x=y$ we have $∀u(u∈x↔u∈y)$; but by logic we have $∀u(u∈y↔u∈x)$ and thus...

Comment: The same for 3): use *transitivity* of $↔$.

Comment: For 4) you need the definition of *ordered pair* (usually based on the *pair* $\{ x,y \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so for the transitivity,$x=y∧y=z \implies∀u(u∈x↔u∈y)  ∧  ∀u(u∈y↔u∈z) \implies ∀u(u∈x↔u∈z) \implies x =z$

Comment: As for the pairing, $\forall x\forall y\exists z (z=\{x,y\}) \implies \forall x \forall y \exists u(u=\{x,\{x,y\}\}) \implies \forall x \forall y \exists u(u=⟨x,y⟩)$

Comment: @JavaLearner. Put these as an answer. We can comment on your answer.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, I posted an answer. I don't have 'flexible screen time', so I am late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** The book you're using does things in an unnecessarily confusing way, and you should consider finding another book to self-learn from.

---

The first two axioms and first three parts of your theorem do make some sense together. The axioms apparently define how the $=$ symbol behaves in the theory, and parts (1), (2), (3) then tell you that those axioms force $=$ to be an equivalence relation. So far so good, and it is indeed an immediate consequence of the second of the axioms. (Mason's answer sketches the beginning of how that works).

However, choosing to have those two axioms in the first place is a rather iffy decision by the book. Generally there are two ways to approach equality in axiomatic set theory:

1. The most common these days is to consider $=$ and its properties to built into the *logic* you reason about sets with. This way, you would develop ways to work with $=$ before you even start speaking about the axioms of *set theory* specifically. Doing things this way, the (1), (2), (3) you quote, as well as the book's "Axiom of Equality" and the "$\to$" direction of its "Axiom of Extensionality" would be axioms *of logic*, not about set theory in particular.
2. Alternatively, for those who want to build set theory with an absolutely minimal logical footprint, declare that your language does not contain an $=$ symbol at all, but when you write $x=y$ it is really an abbreviation for some more complex formula -- which could be either $\forall u(u\in x \leftrightarrow u\in y)$ or $\forall z(x\in z\leftrightarrow y\in z)$. Depending on the choice, either your book's "Axiom of Equality" or its "Axiom of Extensionality" would become vacuous, and the other would be a real axiom that tells you something about sets. Your (1), (2), (3) would then be something you need to prove by unfolding the abbreviation, but the remaining axiom would not be necessary for that.

What the book does seems to be a mixture of the two strategies which gives you the worst of both worlds and the benefit of neither. Apparently it does consider $=$ to be an actual symbol in its language (or it wouldn't need both axioms), but it *doesn't* assume that logic tells you how it works, so you still need to derive the properties of equality by hand.

---

The axioms of "Existence" and "Pairing" are phrased very mysteriously. It looks like the book considers $\emptyset$ and $\{{,}\}$ to be something that is already part of the language -- but if so it ought to present axioms that tell you how they behave. That's not what the two axioms it does give you do. They just assert that the symbols can be *used* -- and *that* is certainly something that pure logic itself already ought to give you, at least once you have proved $\forall x(x=x)$.

The only way I can imagine those two axioms to have any real meaning is if the book has secretly defined the combination "$x = \emptyset$" to be an *abbreviation* of something like $\forall z(z\notin x)$. And the combination "$z=\{x,y\}$" would be an abbreviation of $\forall u(u\in z \leftrightarrow u=x \lor u=y)$.

But if so, the real meat is still in those abbreviations. And it's rather confusing that in *some* contexts you would need $=$ to be a symbol in its own right (otherwise the two first axioms would not both be meaningful), and in *other* contexts it's part of a notation that's an abbreviation.

---

In parts (4) and (5) of the theorem, things get even more confusing, because the notation $\langle x,y\rangle$ suddenly pops out of nowhere. Unless you have axioms for it, it too must be an abbreviation.

It's usual, following [Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski%27s_definition), to define $\langle x,y\rangle$ to mean $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. But this definition will not work "out of the box" unless $\{{,}\}$ is a function symbol, which we have just argued it can't *really* be.

So perhaps the entire combo $z=\langle x,y\rangle$ is an abbreviation, for something like $\exists s\exists t(z=\{s,t\}\land s=\{x,x\}\land t=\{x,y\})$. That would at least *work*. But then the notation $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ is *still* not defined, and you need to appeal to some kind of "of course you can figure out what this *actually* means".

Commonly, presenting general rules for treating notations as function symbols when they're really defined as abbreviated *relations* would be part of the book's development of logic that comes *before* set theory. But I'm getting the impression that such a development has not actually taken place in your book. An author careful enough to do that would certainly have steered clear of the problems with the axioms already presented.

Comment: Maybe it would be valuable for OP to include the title and author?

Answer (score 1):

Just something that may help you get started. Not a complete answer.

**Axiom of extensionality** $\forall x \forall y [x = y ↔ \forall u (u ∈ x ↔ u ∈ y)]$

What happens if we let $x=y$?

Well then $\forall u (u ∈ x ↔ u ∈ y)]$ becomes $\forall u (u ∈ x ↔ u ∈ x)]$ but this must evaluate to true. Because it is saying that a statement implies itself. Something like $S↔S$, But then this implies that $x=x$ as this is the left hand side of this axiom.

Answer (score 1):

For $3$,

$x=y∧y=z \implies  $ (By extensionality )

$∀u(u∈x↔u∈y)∧∀u(u∈y↔u∈z) \implies $ (By the transitivity of $↔$)

$∀u(u∈x↔u∈z) \implies $ (By extensionality)

$x=z$

For 4,

$∀x∀y∃z(z=\{x,y\})$ by the pairing axiom. Now by applying the pairing axiom again we find

$∃u(u=\{x,\{x,y\}\})$. Note that the pairing axiom can be written $∀a∀b∃c(c=\{a,b\})$. We get the desired result by taking $a=x$, $b=z= \{x,y\}$ and $c=u$.

$∀x∀y∃u(u=⟨x,y⟩)$

Comment: I am not sure how to prove  the last one.

Comment: I think we will need your texts definition of $⟨x,y⟩$ to make progress.

Comment: It is $\{x,\{x,y\}\}$

Comment: I think 3 looks fine + I am not sure if we are allowed to use transitivity in middle implication. I worry that we are begging the question but someone who knows more than me will let us know. I am sorry to put your words in your mouth if you wanted to justify the implication in some other way. How would you justify the steps for $4$? These (How?)s are for you to change  as you see fit.

Comment: @Mason, just making sure you recieve a notification.

Comment: Yeah. I am. See if that explanation suits you. I will let the more knowledgeable users take it from here. Also btw, I would think that it would make sense for you to  include the name of the text+author you are using to learn about this stuff in the question.

Comment: I think it's good, but about transitivity in 3, Is it valid? Are we skipping a step or is it right to combine the $\forall u$

Comment: @Mason, Ok, I did the attribution.